# Python operators speed comparison

Tags: python

I want to know the speed between `//` and basic operations like `+ - * /`

```
import time

start = time.time()
for x in range(10**6):
    #a=10-3
    a=10//3
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

They turn out the same speed with offset be reckoned, did I do it right?

Comment: Use the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module instead. That's what it's for.

Comment: It's the same because CPython evaluates both `10-3` and `10//3` at compile time, so you are timing the exact same thing in both cases, namely how long it takes to execute a `LOAD_CONST` operation one million times.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @MattDmo , you can use python's `timeit` module. Examples are given below.

```
>> import timeit
>> timeit.timeit("1+2")
0.02147197723388672
>> timeit.timeit("1/2")
0.03394913673400879
>> timeit.timeit("1*2")
0.012021064758300781
```

This is just an example, you can play around with the module to achieve what you want.
For more details , you can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

## Code

```py
import time

def get_time(process=lambda:[]):
  start = time.time()
  process
  end = time.time()
  return end-start

_test = ["+","-","*","/","//","**"]

op = {'+': lambda x, y: x + y,
      '-': lambda x, y: x - y,
      '*': lambda x, y: x * y,
      '/': lambda x, y: x / y,
      '//': lambda x, y: x // y,
      '**': lambda x, y: x ** y}

for i in _test:
  o = []
  for x in range(3):
    o.append(abs(get_time(lambda:op[i](10,3))))
  print(f"On average time (operator `{i}`): ",sum(o)/len(o))
```

## Output

```
On average time (operator `+`):  2.384185791015625e-07
On average time (operator `-`):  2.384185791015625e-07
On average time (operator `*`):  7.947285970052083e-08
On average time (operator `/`):  7.947285970052083e-08
On average time (operator `//`):  1.5894571940104166e-07
On average time (operator `**`):  7.947285970052083e-08
```